# Why are fonts in Illustrator all paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a .ai file that I've opened in Illustrator. All of the fonts are listed as paths. This is the original file. Any idea how I can update the text?

Comment: If the text is paths then at some point the file was saved that way. There's no way to reverse that operation if the file has been closed and reopened.

Comment: If you have Adobe Acrobat Professional (NOT Adobe Reader) or another capable PDF editor, you can save the file.ai as PDF and open it in Acrobat. There you can apply tool Recognize Text. Sharp vector outlines are recognized generally well if your language is supported. You can copy the texts and replace text images in your file.ai. Important: Hopefully you have a legal right to make a new version. Curved texts are a common method to intentionally make edits difficult when the client hasn't purchased editing rights. By default they do not exist.